# Adding Service Principal in Azure AD programmatically

Tags: authentication, azure, authorization, azure-active-directory

Until now I have been adding my Azure ACS as a Service Principal in Azure AD through PowerShell. I need to automate the process through code but I am struggling to find a way to do it programmatically.

I can see that the PowerShell command-lets use **https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/ProvisioningWebService.svc** for performing all tasks but there is no documentation around it. I was able to capture the traffic in Fiddler but was not able to recreate the tokens and the bindings being used.

Is there any other recommended way to do this kind of stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: These are the powershell commands that I use- 


Connect-MsolService

Import-Module MSOnlineExtended -Force

$replyUrl = New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses –Address "https://**********.accesscontrol.windows.net/"

New-MsolServicePrincipal –ServicePrincipalNames @(“https://*********.accesscontrol.windows.net/”) -DisplayName “HHHHHHH ACS” -Addresses $replyUrl

Answer (score 0):

Er - automation IS powerShell!

Oer are you saying you want to use Azure Automation?

Comment: I want to use C# code do create a service principal in Azure AD.

Comment: at best you're looking for a wrapper around the powershell or js clients that are published.